# Where to find acpi mailing list?

Tags: linux, acpi

Was this mailing list dead:  [Acpi-devel -- Defunct ACPI Development Discussion List](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/acpi-devel)

What other source can I utilize , just want to find the developers of `acpid`

Comment: The link you posted clearly says `Replaced by http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-acpi `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching GMANE](http://news.gmane.org/search.php?match=acpi) (a mailing list archive service) seems helpful, it yields (among others) [`gmane.linux.acpi.devel`](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.linux.acpi.devel/), the *Linux ACPI Development Discussion List*.  While I'm not sure if it's where you'll find the developers of `acpid`, [it is mentioned there](http://search.gmane.org/?query=acpid&group=gmane.linux.acpi.devel), so it might be worth a try.

**Edit** Looking at [Debian's](http://packages.debian.org/acpid) [packages](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/acpid) for the [homepage of some project](http://www.tedfelix.com/linux/acpid-netlink.html) is often helpful, too.

Comment: Sorry , but I'm not sure how to join  `gmane.linux.acpi.devel` news group ?

Comment: @warl0ck: See http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.acpi.devel

Answer (score 0):

The manpage of acpid (http://linux.die.net/man/8/acpid) lists

```
 Tim Hockin <thockin@hockin.org>
```

as author.